# Use UISeachBar with SQLite3

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uisearchbar

I'm pretty new to iphone development.

Anyhow I've searched now for 1,5 hrs to find a possibility/tutorial or whatsoever to add a UISearchBar (it's already added to the RootViewController.XIB).
There are a lot of Tutos describing how to connect an Array to a UISearchBar. 
What I would like to do is connect my already working SQLite Database to the UISearchBar, so that I'm able to do a FullTextSearch.

Like.. let's say I have 100 entries within my UITableView out of the SQLite Database and when I enter a "abc" string then only the relevant entries including abc should be shown.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your UISearchBarDelegate class could establish a connection to the database and run a query somewhere along the lines of:

```
NSString *sql = @"SELECT author FROM books WHERE title like ?||'%'";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
   [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
   -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

   NSString *title = @"programming";
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


   while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
      NSString *author = sqlite3_column_string(stmt, 0);
      NSLog(@"Add to presented authors: %@", author);
   }

}
```

You need to establish a connection to the database before querying it.

There is a nice tutorial [here](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much. The Tutorial helped me a lot!